# how to pass parameters from url to phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

im trying to call my phonegap android app from the URL with parameters.
its working fine but i have no idea how to get the parmeters ive sent with it.
the mainfest looks like that:

```
            </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="ghtr" android:host="com.mds.ghtr"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

the link looks like that:

```
<a href="ghtr://com.mds.ghtr?var1=123456">
```

all i want to do is to get var1 in the js.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By `split` you can get the parameter from `location`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var var1= location.search.split("?var1=")[1]; 
}
```

Or you can get it in Native code .
You need to add this code to  `onCreate` in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String var1= data.getQueryParameter("var1");
}
```

Comment: how i pass var1 to the javascript ?